# How to bind a list of lists to a Listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a List of Lists in C# where each list contains 3 integers

```
List<List<int>> Data = new List<List<int>>();
data.Add(new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3});
```

Now in WPF i have a listbox where i want to bind these values to. The code below is the code i have now but as expected it says there are no "Item" properties.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item2}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Item3}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Could someone explain what i have to do in order to get those numbers showing in the listbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will just have to create a class that has an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to index your bindings within the `ListView` item template, like so:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding [0]}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding [1]}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding [2]}" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However if you plan to have a dynamic number of elements in each `List<int>`, you could place another `ListView` within the original `ListView`.

Also, this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120814100526/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx is really handy if you ever get stuck with binding paths!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `TextBlock` lines like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="{Binding Path=[0]}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Text="{Binding Path=[1]}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Text="{Binding Path=[2]}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inner list will ALWAYS have 3 items, I would suggest making a model for binding. Something like -

```
    public class TripleIntObject
    {
        public int First { get; set; } 
        public int Second{ get; set; }
        public int Third{ get; set; }
    }
```

but hopefully your properties are named with more meaning.

So your list changes from `List<List<int>>` to `List<TripleIntObject>`

Then modify your TextBlocks accordingly -

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="{Binding First}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Text="{Binding Second}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Text="{Binding Third}" />
```

If you plan on dynamic items, I would also suggest changing from `List<TripleIntObject>` to 'ObservableCollection` so that your view will be notified when any data changes. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Rather then creating a new class, probably just easier to use `Tuple<int, int, int>` and use the current bindings in the question

Comment: The only reason I avoided recommending `Tuple` was my lack of knowledge on how well it binds. If you are confident it works fine, I also agree `Tuple<int, int, int>` is the way to go.

Comment: Don’t use Tuple, that’s malpractice. Use something with meaningful names. Your answer is correct, as you stress the need for better naming.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I wouldn't say it was malpractice if the arguments are fairly meaningless, like a math formula etc.. Just allows programmers to be lazy which I think is fine in a scenario like such